# protobuf-net deserialize n'th element in collection

Tags: protobuf-net

Is it possible to deserialize only the second element in a collection using protobuf?

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Lods : List<Lod> { }
```

For example:

```
        myLods = new Lods
        {
            new Lod("garbage"),
            new Lod("interesting"), // this one I need to deserialize
            new Lod("garbage"),
            new Lod("garbage"),
        }
```

Comment: it the list the root object? i.e. was the list the thing that was serialized? or is the list 6 levels down an object tree?

Comment: No, it's not the root object, only a part of the model. I can 'extract' the part of the serialized object using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342318/deserialize-part-of-a-binary-file), using your answer.